# Two For loops working Simultaneously ? bvp4c

Tags: matlab, for-loop, ode, differential-equations

I am trying to solve a differential equation system using bvp4c (boundary conditions). I am using two for loops to solve the functions of bvp4c but the problem is one for loop is done first and then only the last value is used with the iterations of the second for loop, is there a way to make them work simultaneously ? meaning the first iteration of the first for loop uses the first iteration values of the second for loop (not the last as it happens) ? thanks

```
function RTrajfoll(X,Y)
    clf;
    for i = 1:length(X)-1
        init = bvpinit(linspace(X(i),X(i+1),10),[0 0]);
        sol = bvp4c(@Kpath1,@bcpath,init);
        x = linspace(X(i),X(i+1),100);
        BS = deval(sol,x);
        plot(x,BS(1,:),'linewidth',2)
        axis([-2 6 -2 6])
        hold on 
    end

    function bv = bcpath(L,R)
        for j = 1:length(Y)-1
            bv = [L(1)-Y(j) R(1)-Y(j+1)];
        end
    end

end
```

```
%Differential equations dy/dx and dtheta/dx 
function dx = Kpath1(~,c)
    L = 0.12;                        
    r = 0.1;
    WL = 0.25;WR = 0.25;
    y = c(1);th = c(2); 
    dy = tan(th);
    dth = (2*((r*WR)-(r*WL)))/(L*cos(th)*((r*WR)+(r*WL)));
    dx = [dy;dth];
    pose = [y;th];
end
```

Comment: Are `X` and `Y` the same length. I.e., are `for i = 1:length(X)-1` and `for j = 1:length(Y)-1` supposed to correspond to each other?

Comment: yes, both X and Y are the same length

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at @Lutz's answer, you probably don't need a fully-fledged function for `bv`. You may find it more convenient to provide an anonymous function handle, in which case you won't need the third argument:

```
sol = bvp4c(@Kpath1,@(L,R)[L(1)-Y(i) R(1)-Y(i+1)],init);
```

Answer (score 1):

The observed behavior is exactly the expected behavior, you assign repeatedly to `bv`, the return value is the last assigned value.

You will need to pass the index `i` to the boundary condition function, either as a parameter

```
  sol = bvp4c(@Kpath1,@(L,R)bcpath(L,R,i),init);
```

with

```
function bv = bcpath(L,R,j)
      bv = [L(1)-Y(j) R(1)-Y(j+1)];
end
```

or by redefining `bcpath` in every iteration, using the index as global variable,

```
      for i = 1:length(X)-1
        function bv = bcpath(L,R)
          bv = [L(1)-Y(i) R(1)-Y(i+1)];
        end
        init = bvpinit(linspace(X(i),X(i+1),10),[0 0]);
        sol = bvp4c(@Kpath1,@bcpath,init);
...
```